# Enforce SSH to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I have setup a linux server in Amazon Ec2 with a mysql db in RDS.

Connect from mysql workbench to RDS is going fine with (TCP/IP) or (TCP/IP with SSH).

My question is, how to enforce all connections to RDS must going through linux server? I want to enforce this behaviour because it gives an extra layer of security.

**Want to enforce this**

Client -> EC2 Linux Server -> RDS

**Want to stop this**

Client -> RDS

My Ec2 Configuration
[image]

My RDS Configuration
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't simply change the RDS security group to allow connections *only* from the IP address of the EC2 instance?  Because that's the address RDS will see when you tunnel over SSH.

Comment: I wanted to do exactly what you suggest. Tried to set the part that highliged in the picture, but not too sure 1) what ip of the EC-2 should I use (private ip or public)....2) what the port number should be......would be great if you could provide some guide....thanks.

Comment: After playing with it some time, I finally got the desired result by setting the security group id as parameter in the source connection setting. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

**untested**

Try:

```
[client]
protocol=tcp
host=<ip address of DB server>
```

in your my.cnf file.  Where the host can only be accessed via ssh.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  The question appears to be about preventing direct connections to the server.

Comment: Michael, I was assuming that the OP's configuration uses a unix socket for direct connections to localhost if not otherwise specified and that is the problem.  Your suggestion about the security group is more secure and less hackish.

Comment: Unix socket connections aren't possible with RDS, which is a managed MySQL Server service from Amazon Web Services.  The host that runs the RDS instance is not accessible to the RDS customer -- the only possible access is over TCP.

Comment: @fiarce The way you suggested of adding host or bind-address property in my.cnf file is right if MySql is installed in instance. If you want add this type of parameter in RDS then there is `Parameter Group`  for this purpose. But Parameter Group doesn't contain host or bind-address property. So in this case _Michael - sqlbot_ is right according to me.

Comment: I have added some more information related to my server setting, see if it helps you guys a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it some time, I finally got the desired result by setting the security group id as parameter in the source connection setting. Thanks all.